# I need to add the delivery date for the cutom shipping method in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, delivery-date

There are three different types of shipment are there I need to add the delivery for each one for shipment 1 it's standard delivery within 3 days, shipment method 2 the customer needs to choose the delivery date with date picker, shipment 3 the delivery will be within 21 days

**I need to add the different delivery date for each method.**

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: There are three different types of shipment are there I need to add the delivery for each one for shipment 1 it's standard delivery within 3 days, shipment method 2 the customer needs to choose the delivery date with date picker, shipment 3 the delivery will be within 21 days